# Why does using a reference inside of a match result in "cannot move out of dereference"?

Tags: rust

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not valid Rust 1.0 code. Updated versions of this code produce different errors, but the answers still contain valuable information.

I don't understand why the following code is not working.

```
use std::string::String;
use std::str;

fn append_byte_to_string(string: &String, bytes: &[u8]) {
     let msg = str::from_utf8(bytes);
     match msg {
        Some(msg_str) => {
            string.append("plop");//msg_str);
        },  
        None => {}
    }   
}

fn main() {
    append_byte_to_string(&String::new(), [64,65]);
}
```

I've got the following error:

```
test.rs:8:4: 8:10 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
test.rs:8                       string.append("plop");//msg_str);
                                ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I've seen [explanations](http://paulkoerbitz.de/posts/Understanding-Pointers-Ownership-and-Lifetimes-in-Rust.html), but I don't understand how it is applicable to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `&String`: an *immutable* reference to a `String` object. Your method will need to take `&mut String` in order to be able to mutate the string:

```
use std::str;

fn append_byte_to_string(string: &mut String, bytes: &[u8]) {
    if let Ok(msg) = str::from_utf8(bytes) {
        string.push_str(msg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    append_byte_to_string(&mut String::new(), &[64, 65]);
}
```

By the way, you want [`push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) rather than [`append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.append), as `append` (or in Rust 1.0, [`Add::add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html)) consumes its argument and returns it, whereas `push_str` takes `&mut self`.